# List<Integer> objects in order of length

Tags: java, list, object

Write code for a Comparator object that orders `List<Integer>` objects in order of
their length.

So I know how to write the comparator but i'm confused as to how I can add objects to a `List<Integer>` so that the list contains for example: [1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],[99,102,301,31,31].

Or am i misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: You don't - you would add `List<Integer>` values into a `List<List<Integer>>` or something similar.

Comment: Looks like you have a `List<Integer[]>`, and not a `List<Integer>`

Comment: If i used `List<List<Integer>>` how do i add multiple lists within it? If we used arrayList, would it just be .add(value)? How would i get it to start a new list within the list? (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `List.size()` for comparison

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `Comparator` that sorts `Collection` objects. This can be done generically. Particularly, the fact that the `Collection` in your case is a `List` is not relevant for the sorting. And the fact that your `Collection` contains `Integer` objects is even less relevant. You can write one generic `Comparator` that can sort `List<Integer>` objects as well as `LinkedHashSet<String>` objects. The only relevant part is the `Collection#size()` method.

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionBySizeComparatorTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list0 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1,2);
        List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        List<Integer> list4 = Arrays.asList(1);
        List<List<Integer>> lists = 
            Arrays.asList(list0, list1, list2, list3, list4);

        System.out.println("Before sorting");
        for (List<Integer> list : lists)
        {
            System.out.println(list);
        }

        Collections.sort(lists, collectionBySizeComparator());

        System.out.println("After sorting");
        for (List<Integer> list : lists)
        {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }

    private static Comparator<Collection<?>> 
        collectionBySizeComparator()
    {
        return new Comparator<Collection<?>>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Collection<?> c0, Collection<?> c1)
            {
                return Integer.compare(c0.size(), c1.size());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is homework. Giving away a full answer is usually not a good way of helping.

Comment: @aioobe It has never been mentioned that this is homework. This is not a tutorial or "homework support size", but a **Question and Answer** site. However, no need to repeat an old discussion here (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812)

Comment: @aioobe Apart from that: A websearch would have brought hundreds of results like the solution that you proposed (which was only missing a single line). However, this solution does not teach the asker how to write ("good", versatile) generic methods. So even if my solution was not a "good way of helping" for the asker and his homework tasks, maybe it was a *good way of helping* those who want to give good help for homework tasks, but accidentally are giving help that leads into the wrong direction. Too meta? Maybe.